# xmlns attribute not produced for nested elements

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xml-namespaces, xmlserializer

I have a class with a nested list of another class, like this:

```
public class Departement {
     [XmlElement (Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
     string Id;
     [XmlElement (Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
     List<Student> listStident = new List<Student> ();
 }
 public class Student 
 {
     [XmlElement (Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
     string firstName;
     [XmlElement (Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
     string lastName;
 }
```

When I try to serialize an array of `Departement`s, I get an xml like that:

```
<ArrayOfDepartement xmlns="http://www.w3...">
    <Departement>
        <id xmlns== "http://tempuri.org/">1234567890</id>
        <Student xmlns== "http://tempuri.org/">
            <firstName>med</firstName>
            <lastName>ali</lastName>
        </Student>
        <Student xmlns== "http://tempuri.org/">
            <firstName>joe</firstName>
            <lastName>doe</lastName>
        </Student>
    </Departement>
</ArrayOfDepartement>
```

No namespace attribute is generated for the nested elements. The code I use to serialize is:

```
public void Serialize(object oToSerialize)
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer =  new XmlSerializer(oToSerialize.GetType());
    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(stream, oToSerialize);
        stream.Flush();
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        xDoc.Load(stream);
    }
}
```

Comment: And the question or problem is what?

Comment: No namespace for the attributes of the nested objects.

Comment: What attribute? There are no attributes except `xmlns` in the sample XML.

Comment: Attribute of the class student (firstName, lastName) they don't get the namespace (or attribute xmlns) i want them like taht: <firstName xmlns="...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XML Namespaces specification [in section 6.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#scoping-defaulting) states:

> The scope of a namespace declaration declaring a prefix extends from the beginning of the start-tag in which it appears to the end of the corresponding end-tag, excluding the scope of any inner declarations with the same NSAttName part. In the case of an empty tag, the scope is the tag itself.
>
> Such a namespace declaration applies to all element and attribute names within its scope whose prefix matches that specified in the declaration.

Therefore, the data structure is serialized *without* repeated `xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"` attributes on the nested `firstName` and `lastName` elements as they would be superfluous. The reason why `id` and each `Student` elements have their own `xmlns` atribute is that they are siblings, forming disjoint namespace declaration scopes.

In other words, the XML produced by your code is correct and as expected. If there were extra `xmlns` attributes on the nested elements, it would have no semantical effect. I would be more concerned about the fact that that you are not serializing a specific root class but a plain `Departement[]` (unless it's just for debugging / experimenting purposes).

Comment: Ok thanks. But what if i need the namespace to be repeated? Who can i do that?

Comment: Why would you need it? It's not necessary.

Comment: I'm trying to call a method of a web service that have complex object parameter using WebClient. I serialize my object (that have the same structure of the parameter) and deserialize it as the type of the parametre, the elements of the xmlDoc that don't have the specific namespace, does not appear in the new object.

Comment: Then post a separate question describing this exact problem showing the specific code. Most likely the problem is elsewhere, not in the fact that the nested elements have no `xmlns` attributes which would be superfluous anyway.

Comment: I was wrong, the namespace does not affect the deserialization. Perhaps i should get uninitialized instances of nested objects? But that's an other problem.

Comment: I will do that monday, because the source code is in VM and i have to write it all from zero here.